# Problem uploading me laravel project to server

Tags: laravel, server

I made a new Laravel Project and tried to upload it to my server using Filezilla.
After uploading all the maps in the project the server can't seem to read the blade functions, it also doesn't use or see the correct routing placed in the web.php.

If I route to "ServerName/resources/views/welcome.blade.php" I do get a page, but in there all the added blade functions are shown on screen.

I eddited the Index.php file, there I change the routhing path as thats something a lot of online tutorials said.

Comment: Needs more info. What webserver are you using? Is it set up correct (`public/` as "DocumentRoot")? Does your server support PHP? Does it support `.htaccess`?

Comment: "_If I route to ..._" _If_ your server were set up correct you would not be able to "route" to any file outside of the `public` folder

Comment: @brombeer I am hosting this on one.com, they do support PHP on there servers.
as for if it's setup correctly I am sadly not sure, I have never done anything like this before and thus don't know anything of it. I followed a youtube tutorial on how to upload a laravel project to a server and followed every step they did on there.

Comment: Do you tried to reload vendor folder in the server?

Comment: @Michu I just tried it, no diffrence.

Comment: Is Laravel throwing an exception?

Comment: @Michu no I get "mostly" the normal laravel page only now the Auth function is also displayed as text on the welcome page, no errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Check .htaccess file.
Must be somthing Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just checked, my htaccess has the exact same content in it.

Comment: did you try these artisan commands?

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear

Comment: I don't know where I can use those commands on the server. I'l look for it and then try them.

Comment: you should cd into root of project and run these 3 commands.